# What do I support with Bitcoin Core Version 0.14.2

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, full-node, segwit2x, bip148-uasf

At the moment I'm following the discussion about BIP-141, BIP-148, SegWit and SegWit2x (NYA). But I'm confused.

I'm running Bitcoin Core Version v0.14.2 as a full-node. It's currently downloading the blockchain (should finish in 40 hours). So I count as a *user* (in regard to the term *user activated soft fork*) what means that I have a vote.

**Now I'm wondering what I'm supporting by using version 0.14.2?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the `version` field of blocks generated by that software, there are websites that show both the client and version.
To my knowledge, core supports bip141, which is SegWit (bit 1 of version)
Core does not support bip91, nor bip148, nor Segwit2x (2mb hardfork)

Comment: Note that BIP148 and BIP91 are soft forks without impact on transaction validity. This means that any software - including Core - that does not support these forks will accept the longest valid chain, regardless of whether these rules get adopted by the network.